# Htaccess redirect not displaying values

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

so I'm trying to make a pretty URL using htaccess

I want to convert `www.domain.com/r.php?id=123` to `www.domain.com/r/123`

I used this htaccess code to do it :-

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^r/([0-9]*)/([a-z]*)$ ./r.php?user=$1
```

However, on r.php, when I try to get the value of ID..I get

```
/Library/WebServer/Documents/ico/main/r.php:2:
array (size=0)
  empty
```

Here;s my r.php file

```
<?php
var_dump($_REQUEST);
?>
```

What am I doing wrong in here?

Comment: The pattern `^r/([0-9]*)/([a-z]*)$` doesn't match the given URL `/r/123` as it requires a trailing `/`

Comment: @CD001 What must I write then?

Comment: Try `^r/([0-9]*)(?:/([a-z]*))?$` - that will also prevent things like `/r/123abc` from working (which would happen if you just make the middle `/` optional)

Comment: @CD001
This is my updated line now `RewriteRule ^r/([0-9]*)(?:/([a-z]*))?$ ./r.php?user=$1` but I still get an empty array

Comment: It's working on my dev box...

Answer (score 0):

If your link contains id then make sure in your .htaccess rewrite rule you are actually using id. So just follow this logic:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule whatever/r/(.*)script_name.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I still get an empty array

Comment: Please re-post exactly what changes did You apllied to your link, script name and rewrite rule in your .htaccess.

Comment: Well, this code works on my dev box, however I just realize that your question is two questions actually. In part two you want to get id value from link. Just use GET id.